# SOAPUI: не получается получить содержимое тэгов xml в data source через data source loop из респонса soap-запроса

Tags: xml, soapui

Может кто подскажет по SOAPUI. Есть такая проблема, получаю от YandexSpeller-а xml со списком ошибок в словах. XML приходит вида https://pastebin.com/0E44WH2a . Структура простая как видно, я хочу забрать отсюда дата сорсом через датасорслуп каждую ошибку и её параметры закинуть в ексельку. Так вот, аттрибуты len и pos достаются нормально через @len и @pos, а когда пытаюсь взять содержимое тега word, readyapi кидает ошибку без содержимого.
Вот пример ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением "ns1:" (который я объявил выше, в блоке Row xpath) к названию тэгов word и s в блоке Column xpath.